# Get a frequency table for a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

Suppose I have the DataFrame where I have a column of lists.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b'], ['c'], ['a', 'b']]})
```

with the output

```
Index  A
0      ['a', 'b', 'c']
1      ['b']
2      ['c']
3      ['a', 'b']
```

How do I get a frequency table for how often a list appears in the column?

The ideal output would look like

```
A               Count
['a', 'b', 'c'] 1
['b']           1
['c']           1
['a', 'b']      1
```

Attempting something like this...

```
df.A.value_counts()
```

leads to the error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` to tuples, lists are not hashable as the error suggests:

```
df.A.map(tuple).value_counts().rename_axis('A').reset_index(name='Count')

           A  Count
0  (a, b, c)      1
1     (a, b)      1
2       (b,)      1
3       (c,)      1
```